# Issue while trying to use a tag

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use this tag which allows me to check if a map got permissions in the site I'm working on using `Geonode`.

```
{% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.get_self_resource as "layer_perms" %}
{% if "view_resourcebase" in layer_perms %}
```

When I used it in other files, everything works fine but in this one, the page I'm on crash and when I check the apache log I have this problem.

```
[Thu Sep 12 01:05:26.388898 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18375:tid 140402620434176] VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [resource] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}, {'facet_type': 'layers', 'is_layer': True, u'view': <django.views.generic.base.TemplateView object at 0x7fb1dce66390>}]"
```

Here is the `views.py` of this folder. I'm not used to doing web so I'm not familiar with those `views.py, models.py,` etc, I mean maybe it works in the other file because the `views.py` are different in them? I don't really know and I would appreciate some explanation if someone knows why this issue appears.

```
import json

from django.utils import timezone
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken
from oauth2_provider.exceptions import OAuthToolkitError, FatalClientError
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse

from guardian.models import Group


def verify_access_token(key):
    try:
        token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=key)

        if not token.is_valid():
            raise OAuthToolkitError('AccessToken is not valid.')
        if token.is_expired():
            raise OAuthToolkitError('AccessToken has expired.')
    except AccessToken.DoesNotExist:
        raise FatalClientError("AccessToken not found at all.")

    return token


def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip


@csrf_exempt
def verify_token(request):
    No need to check authentication (see Issue #2815)
    if (not request.user.is_authenticated()):
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'error': 'unauthorized_request'
            }),
            status=403,
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    """

    if (request.POST and request.POST['token']):
        try:
            token = verify_access_token(request.POST['token'])
        except Exception, e:
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({
                    'error': str(e)
                }),
                status=403,
                content_type="application/json"
            )

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'client_id': token.application.client_id,
                'issued_to': token.user.username,
                'user_id': token.user.id,
                'email': token.user.email,
                'verified_email': 'true',
                'access_type': 'online',
                'expires_in': (token.expires - timezone.now()).total_seconds() * 1000
            }),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'error': 'invalid_request'
        }),
        status=403,
        content_type="application/json"
    )


@csrf_exempt
def roles(request):
    """
    Check IP whitelist / blacklist
    """
    if settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST and not get_client_ip(request) in settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'error': 'unauthorized_request'
            }),
            status=403,
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    groups = [group.name for group in Group.objects.all()]
    groups.append("admin")

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'groups': groups
        }),
        content_type="application/json"
    )


@csrf_exempt
def users(request):
    """
    Check IP whitelist / blacklist
    """
    if settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST and not get_client_ip(request) in settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'error': 'unauthorized_request'
            }),
            status=403,
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    user_name = request.path_info.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    User = get_user_model()

    if user_name is None or not user_name or user_name == "users":
        users = [user for user in User.objects.all()]
    else:
        users = [user for user in User.objects.filter(username=user_name)]

        if not users:
            # Try using the user email
            users = [user for user in User.objects.filter(email=user_name)]

    json_object = []
    for user in users:
        groups = [group.name for group in user.groups.all()]
        if user.is_superuser:
            groups.append("admin")

        json_object.append({
            'username': user.username,
            'groups': groups
        })

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'users': json_object
        }),
        content_type="application/json"
    )


@csrf_exempt
def admin_role(request):
    """
    Check IP whitelist / blacklist
    """
    if settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST and not get_client_ip(request) in settings.AUTH_IP_WHITELIST:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'error': 'unauthorized_request'
            }),
            status=403,
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'adminRole': 'admin'
        }),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

Comment: You probably missed providing the **`resource`** key in the context from the view function/class. Anyway check it or show us your view

Comment: @JPG I edit the question, have a look.

Comment: Where are you using the above template? I can't find a one related to the issue

Comment: I'm using them in over html files